# JQuery Mobile Mail Form - capturing data from "select" field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used the following solution for a mailer form for my JQuery Mobile site:

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/06/29/creating-a-contact-form-in-jquery-mobile-and-php/

Everything works fine, except the "required" function does not properly parse values for HTML "select" elements:

```
$('.required', $contactform).each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        error++;
    } 
}); // each
```

In other words, whenever I add the class "required" to a "select" form element, the form will not submit because it always triggers the error "Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk" regardless of what item is selected.

Source article is from June 2011, so my guess is that this function doesn't work with my version of JQuery (1.8.3) or JQM (1.3.2).

I'm not a Javascript expert, and this article unfortunately provides little documentation as to how exactly this function works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of the line that you have:

```
$('.required', $contactform).not('span').each(function (i) {
```

Comment: @auralsun jQueryMobile is adding a `span` element related to the `select` that it wasn't adding in the older version and giving it the `required` class.  So when you select `$('.required', $contactform)`, it's returning that `span` in the set, which you don't want.